# activerecord-jdbc-adapter DB2 zOS increment ID issue

Tags: activerecord, db2, jruby, zos

## Short

ID column doesn't increment with INSERT INTO.

## Long

I'm with:

- JRuby 1.7.11
- activerecord (3.2.17)
- activerecord-jdbc-adapter (1.3.6)
- DB2 v10 on z/OS (Mainframe) (driver db2jcc4.jar version 4.15.99)

### /config/database.yml:

```
production:                                                                     
  adapter: jdbc                                                                 
  driver: com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver                                             
  url: jdbc:db2://142.123.123.123:123/D2TZMSTR                                  
  connection_alive_sql: "SELECT 1 FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1 FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY"
  host: 142.123.123.123                                                          
  port: 123                                                                    
  database: ESTIPROD                                                            
  tablespace: ESTIMATE                                                          
  username: monkey                                                              
  password: business                                                            
  encoding: unicode                                                             
  Blockquote
```

### db/migrate/create_bid.rb:

```
class CreateBids < ActiveRecord::Migration  
  def self.up                               
    create_table :practices, :primary_key => "practice_id", :force => true do |t|
      t.string :practice_no,        :null => false, :limit => 3                  
      t.string  :practice_name,     :null => false, :limit => 50     
      t.timestamps                                                               
    end                                                                          

    # Create alternate index for practice_no                                     
    add_index :practices, :practice_no                                           

    # Populate Practice table with practices who including into BID project                                                                                  
    Practice.create(:practice_no   => '001',                                     
                    :practice_name => 'Mainframe'                                
    )                                                                            

    Practice.create(:practice_no   => '002',                                     
                   :practice_name => 'Unix'                                     
    )                                                                            
...
end
```

I got the following message from my mainframe when I do the 'rake db:migrate' command:

> ActiveRecord::JDBCError: com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlIntegrityConstraintViolationException: 
>   DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-803, SQLSTATE=23505, SQLERRMC=PRAC19S5;0000000201, >DRIVER=4.15.99: 
>   INSERT INTO practices (created_at, 
>                         practice_id, 
>                         practice_name, 
>                         practice_no, 
>                         updated_at)
>   VALUES ('2014-03-26 19:27:31.749000', 
>          **0**, 
>          'Unix', 
>          '002', 
>          '2014-03-26 19:27:31.749000')

From IBM :

> -803
>   AN INSERTED OR UPDATED VALUE IS INVALID BECAUSE THE INDEX IN INDEX SPACE indexspace-name >CONSTRAINS COLUMNS OF THE TABLE SO NO TWO ROWS CAN CONTAIN DUPLICATE VALUES IN THOSE >COLUMNS. RID OF EXISTING ROW IS X record-id

We all understand that the value should be:

```
VALUES ('2014-03-26 19:27:31.749000', 
        1, 
        'Unix', 
        '002', 
        '2014-03-26 19:27:31.749000')
```

### SELECT * FROM PRACTICES:

```
    | PRACTICE_ID | PRACTICE_NO | PRACTICE_NAME | CREATED_AT                 | UPDATED_AT                 |  
  1_|           0 | 001         | Mainframe     | 2014-03-26-19.27.29.279000 | 2014-03-26-19.27.29.279000 |
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: Granted, I don't know Ruby but I don't see where you set `practice_id` to 1 in your code.

Comment: Rails manage it.  It works with other databases like H2, MySQL and DB2 express-C on Linux side.